# How to make plots 'blacker'?

Tags: plotting, color

I need to make a contour plot for publication, but even if I set `ContourStyle->Black`, the 'black' plots and the axes are very faint. When I export the figure in svg and open it in some image-processing software (inkscape), the colour shown for the selected plot is actually a 'gray' colour instead of 'black' in rgb scale.

[image]

As shown in the figure, it is obvious the dashed line is a lot darker than the gridlines and tick markers. How to make the Gridlines, the tick markers and everything appear darker (not thicker, I am happy with the current thickness)?

Comment: What if you save the graphics as a pdf?

Comment: Does `ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[1]]` help?

Comment: Setting the `Opacity` and `GrayLevel` does help. Thanks. But that only applies to the contour lines and still I don't know how I can make the tick markers (2, pi, pi/2, etc) darker

Comment: `..., FrameStyle -> Black]` should drive frame components, including tick marks, to `Black`.

Comment: yeah `FrameStyle->Black` does make it work. thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not actually sure how to test your specific case, but this seems to work:

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Black, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
List@InputForm@Cases[cp, _?ColorQ, Infinity]
(*
  {{GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[0], 
    GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[0]}]}
*)

Cases[cp, _Opacity, Infinity]
(*  {}  *)
```